# Hot to make pyplot go from left border to right

Tags: matplotlib

So my plot start from left border to right border if I use up to 10 values. From 11 on it either touches one border or neither. I would like plots to touch the borders. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import pylab
import numpy as np

pylab.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
a = 0; b = 11;
aaa = np.arange(0.5, 20,0.5)
ax.plot(aaa[0:b], [1]*b, label="aaa")
fig.savefig("aaa-times.png")
```

Pictures of plots:

Up to 10 values:

[image]

11 values or more:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set axis limits, to make them touch the borders you could set to minimum and maximum,

```
ax.set_xlim([aaa[0:b].min(),aaa[0:b].max()])
```

or for 11 onward,

```
ax.plot(aaa[b:], [1]*(aaa.shape[0]-b), label="aaa")
ax.set_xlim([aaa[b:].min(),aaa[b:].max()])
```

Comment: Yes this is it. Thanks!